# Sending an HTTP API Request in Python and get json data to csv format

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, api, httprequest

I have HTTP URL and API request body, i need to post the request using python and get output in json and  convert into csv file.
As i am new to this python, couldn't succeed. Can any one please help me on this.

URL: as below
http://{{WEBURL}}:{{WEBPORT}}/{{TENANT_ID}}/api/requesttrackingservice/get

API body as below

```
{
  "params": {
    "query": {
      "filters": {
        "typesCriterion": [
          "tasksummaryobject"
        ], 

        "propertiesCriterion": [
          {
            "modifiedDate": {
              "gte": "2019-08-26T06:00:00.000-0500",
               "lte": "2019-08-30T19:00:00.000-0500",
              "type": "_DATETIME"
            }
          }
        ],
            "attributesCriterion": [
          {
            "connectIntegrationType": {
              "eq": "ENTITY_IMPORT"
            }
          },
            {
            "profileName": {
              "eq": "sys_import_data_json_eventhub_task_base"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "fields": {
      "attributes": [
        "status","totalRecordsProcessed","totalRecordsCreate","totalRecordsupdate","totalRecordsDelete","filetype"
      ],
      "relationships": [
        "_ALL"
      ]
    },
    "options": {
      "maxRecords": 1000
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: look into requests

Answer (score 0):

Assigning your url to a `URL` variable, and your json to a `JSON` variable, you could try:

```
import requests
response = requests.post(url=URL, json=JSON)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Thank you, however we are not passing any authentication, do we need to mention that authentication ie, client-id &client-secret in  JSON header?

Comment: So you'd have to look at the API documentation if it exists to see what data is required for your request. By looking at your url, I'd say it's a REST API and some of those require you to pass some sort of authentication (whether basic or an OAuth or token of some sort).  You can try sending a request without any authentication key values and then review your status code and content and the API may tell you if you need to login first.